Mage Knight The Board Game : Where Reputation plays a role?
In Mage Knight, reputation is important when spending influence at some sites for reducing or increasing the influence costs. I am looking for a list of sites where the player's reputation is used as a modifier during the interaction with the site and which sites the reputation track is ignored and instead you only use raw influence.
The list of sites:

Buying healing from a village
Buying healing from a Monastery
Buying AA Cards from a Monastery
Buying Spells from a Mage Tower
Green City : Buying AA Cards
Blue City : Buying Spells
White City : Buying Units
Red City : Buying Artefacts

At all cities you gain, Once per turn, +1 Influence for each of your own shields on city.
